# how can define variable on heap in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I want to declare a new variable on heap ( I don't want use stack) .
how can I do it? I want to know the instruction?
assume that there are 10 variable that use stack and i want to change the location of them and put them on heap.

Comment: What assembly? x86? Arm? Please add a suitable tag.

Comment: Gnu assembler: in section `.data`: `myvariable .dword 0`

Comment: x86
thank for your notification

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Seriously? The data segment doesn't contain the heap, does it? In assembler, the heap is on the stack.

Comment: What assembler? GAS, TASM, MASM, NASM ?

Comment: In assembler there's no real concept of heap. Nevertheless, one can implement "heap grows upwards, stack grows downwards" in `.data` segment and assigning `esp` to the bottom of the preallocated area.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I want to change memory location. the stack use some location and heap use another memory location , I want to transfer the variable on stack to heap , and use that memory location

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: this is a part of program code:
".data?
buffer db 512 dup(?)
hFile dd ?"
these are in data stack of program during running, I want put them in the heap location memory , and use them , how can do this"?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: I always thought the heap was in the stack segment, not the data segment. The data segment is for (mutable) static storage, non? Anyway, modern heaps don't use `sbrk` so much as `mmap` (or equivalent), so the notion of a specific segment being used for the heap is maybe not even appropriate.

Comment: Heap is not a specific place, so you can't "define" anything in the heap, only the pointer to some location on the heap. You must call some memory allocating function to get the address. You may declare some struct type for easier access if there are multiple variable types in your code

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc thank for your comment , but I have two question :
1) "call some memory allocating function" it means I must use some API like memalloc to get heap place? If I don't want to use API how can I do that?
2 ) "You may declare some struct type for easier access" what type can I declare in assembly for access?( say an example)

Comment: There isn't "an instruction" to use heap memory. Heap memory is a separate pool of memory somewhere which is managed using some functions that you can call to allocate portions of it. Unless you want to define your own pool of memory in your program or your own library along with the functions to use it and maintain it, the easiest thing to do to use heap would be to link to and use the C library `malloc` and `free` routines. If you don't have access to those, you could do something perhaps *ad hoc* specific to your application.

Comment: @mbratch
thank for your answer , but I don't mean the last thing you say "you could do something perhaps ad hoc specific to your application " , if I don't want to use C function how can I do that?please give more detail

Comment: @RF27 rolling your own heap and heap manager is a lot of work in the general case. Why are you wanting to avoid the C library? And why do you need a heap?

Answer (score 3):

Easy answer, write a simple application in C that uses `getmem`.
Pick up a disassembler and look at the x64 code the compiler generates.
You'll have to reproduce the same code in your assembler.

Longer answer:
There is no x64 instruction for putting stuff on the heap, it takes about a 100 instructions to do that, that's why people call a library function.
The library functions are highly optimized, so don't bother reinventing that wheel.
Once you've got the memory reference, it's just a simple pointer. Assembly excels at pointer manipulation so that should be easy.